# Proof validity methods other than truth tables

Tags: logic, proof, validity

I have read or heard some time ago that truth tables cannot be used to validate arguments which involves the use of quantifiers i.e. in [predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic) or quantificational logic where you can find statements like "*All men are animals*" or "*No man is animal*" along with conditional if statements.

Are there more accurate or similar method(s) out there like truth tables?

Answer (score 1):

For *predicate logic* we have to use proof procedures, like :

- [Natural Deduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction)
- [Tableaux method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux)
- [Sequent calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus)

but there is no [decision procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) like truth table for proposistional logic.

You can see some textbook :

- Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521008042) (2003).
- Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199215626) (2007).

Comment: I had previously read this [book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1285196546/) where I studied predicate logic. So, if I just need to know the proof validity method should I really need to start with mathematical logic?

Comment: @cpx - basically, Hurley use *Natural Deduction* : it's ok. He treats also predicate logic, with the "counterexample method" (like Tableau).